# MySQL Trigger Syntax Problems - If Statement&GO

Tags: mysql

i know i should probably read how to get into the mysql syntax first but i'm short on time on this. So i wanted to ask for help here.

This was a trigger from sql- server and i need to transfer this into mysql. I did the change on a few lines but am stuck now.

There is a Syntax Error with the if- statement. "unexpected 'IF'"   (tried case when ... but also got an error)
And another one before the Alter- table- command at the end. "GO is not a valid input at this point"

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
    TEST_TRIGGER

    AFTER insert
ON
    TEST_TABLE

For each row

BEGIN

    SET v_ANZAHL = (select COUNT(1) from inserted),

    IF v_ANZAHL = 1 then 

    DELETE FROM 
        filter_group
    WHERE 
    filter_groups_id IN
        (select FilterID from filter_groups_view);

INSERT INTO filter_group
           (filter_groups_id
           ,group_id)

SELECT
    FilterID,
    GruppeID

FROM
    filter_groups_view

END

GO

ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE ENABLE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER

GO
```

Comment: Typo: You should have `;` at the end of the `SET` line, not `,`.

Comment: You're right! Smh after changing mysql warns about a missing semicolon. Before with the comma there was no error. This is quite confusing.

Comment: You also need semicolon before `END`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors:

- delimiter change before and after
- some ; missing
- end if missing (Don't know, if it's at the right place now)

Here is the code corrected, but untested because of missing tables and contents:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 
    TEST_TRIGGER

    AFTER insert
ON
    TEST_TABLE

For each row

BEGIN

    SET v_ANZAHL = (select COUNT(1) from inserted);

    IF v_ANZAHL = 1 then 

    DELETE FROM 
        filter_group
    WHERE 
    filter_groups_id IN
        (select FilterID from filter_groups_view);

INSERT INTO filter_group
           (filter_groups_id
           ,group_id)
SELECT
    FilterID,
    GruppeID

FROM
    filter_groups_view;

END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```